# Scala Play messages file to inline or reuse the version in build.sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have a Scala Play project and currently I show the current application version at some location in my main template. The version I can easily define in the `conf/messages` file. However, since I have an automated build for creating releases, the release iterations will update the `build.sbt` increasing the version according to the release there e.g. `version := "1.0.6-SNAPSHOT"`

I could use the same mechanics during the release to update my `conf/messages` file as well  but instead I would prefer to have my `conf/messages` file including the version information from `build.sbt` e.g. alla `application.version=${sbt.application.version}`.

How can I accomplish this? is it possible at all?

UPDATE: it is worth mentioning that in Maven these build settings become Java system properties and can be easily used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sbt-buildinfo`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) plugin to generate a Scala source based on the `build.sbt`.

The plugin generates a `BuildInfo` object, which contains information you can then use to display the application version.

Otherwise I don't think you can access sbt information from your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [xsbt-filter](https://github.com/sdb/xsbt-filter) plugin to achieve this. It basically works like Maven's resource filtering mechanism, and exposes the project's name, version, etc. by default. You can further configure it to expose other properties.